# AVR Byte Storage

Tags: assembly, avr, atmega

Hey I'm new to assembly programming with the AVR family but familiar with uC's like the PIC. What I'm confused about right now is the following excerpt from some sample code.

```
.dseg
.org 0x0100

RegA: .byte 1
RegB: .byte 1
RegC: .byte 1

....
```

With the PIC family, you specify the address of the labeled register right after defining the label. In the AVR family however with this syntax I'm not sure where `RegC` is stored. I understand that the SRAM on the ATMega328P is 16-bits wide so this means that `RegA` and `RegB` are stored at `0x0100`? And as a result the stack pointer automatically increments and stores RegC at the address `0x0101`?

Comment: Is the first line really `.desg` and not `.dseg`?  What toolchain are ou using to compile this?

Comment: @DavidGrayson sorry, typo and the avr-gcc toolchain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks this code defines three one-byte variables in data memory (RAM).

- RegA would be stored at 0x0100 (this is the address of a *byte* in RAM, not a 16-bit word or anything like that)
- RegB would be stored at 0x0101
- RegC would be stored at 0x0102

If you are able to compile and link this code, you should be able to look at the disassembly listing or map file to verify this.

Comment: I'll verify as soon as I can, but does the compiler increment the address automatically? Is there somewhere in the ATMega 328P manual you could point me to or any manual that describes the increment?

Comment: Here is the documentation for `.byte` in the GNU assembler:  https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.32/as/Byte.html#Byte  There isn't much documentation for it but I think it's pretty clear that it needs to increment the current address, or else there would be no point in it taking multiple expressions, since each expression would overwrite the last.

Comment: its not incrementing, .byte with one item listed is one byte in size, so if you say I have three byte and have labels on each then the first label is at 0x100 in this case it is one byte in size so the next thing is at address 0x101 and is one byte in size and so on.  change one of them to .byte 1,7 and see that it now consumes 2 bytes